# IPtables does'nt apply this rule

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, iptables

I got many rules like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
modprobe ip_conntrack
# Initialiser les tables
iptables -t filter -F

#Vider les règles custom
iptables -t filter -X

#Interdire toutes les connexions entrante et sortantes
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP


#Works perfect
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s myIP --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT

#Don't work
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s myIP --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I've reloaded many times /etc/init.d/firewall, rebooted nothing is working, nmap output say :

```
Host is up (0.017s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

I checked mysql service is running too. what I am doing wrong ? I don't understand. thank you.

Comment: you need to add a rule to accept RELATED,ESTABLISHED connections.
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

In your final rule,  you're using specifying the `--dport` on the `OUTPUT` table - which is the destination port of the outgoing (server to client) packet. This isn't the service port 3306 - this will be the client's ephemeral port. Instead, if you wish to restrict the outgoing packets for the MySQL service, you should consider using the `--sport 3306` ito allow outgoing MySQL packets.

Comment: Also `-s myIP`. Sounds like it should be `-d` instead.

Comment: I understand for the output rule but the same rules as I wrote works like a cahrm for my ssh console so why it doesn't work ?
Why -d instead of -s for the source ip ?
not better : 
Host is up (0.017s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

Comment: I restarted  just by sh /etc/init.d/firewall but I'm unable to connect to mariadb...

Comment: iptable -L output : 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  laubervilliers-XX-X-XXX-XXX.w81-XXX.abo.xxx.fr  anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
